# Firebase Query for arranging of RecyclerView items based on timestamp value of the lastMessageKey stored under Firebase generated Instance Ids

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

My Firebase Database tree

[image]

I am trying to query for the "lastMessageKey" field stored under the lastMessage branch in Firebase Database.

Problems :
1) "lastMessage" branch has a child "7KSk3TO58UZQd7KewlC2eNhdMj92" this is the current user id so, I can fetch it but below this is another child "other User's userId" just the parent of "lastMessageKey" field. And I want to order the Query by the lastMessageKey value's creation time. But I donot know the other userIds in the query, so I am unable to use orderByChild("lastMessageKey").

2) Note : lastMessageKey value is a pushKey generated by push(), so we can get it's creation time as said in - 1).

Answer (score 0):

```
chatsQuery = mRootRef.child("lastMessage").child(mCurrent_user_id).orderByChild("lastMessageKey");
```

Here I didnot require to pass the child between the current userid and the lastMessageKey ie.the other userIds. I was directly able to jump to "lastMessageKey" value ordering upon providing the start path with child("mCurrent_user_id"). And this solved,my problem.